# Hotel like Wifi manager

Tags: wireless-networking, authentication

Does anyone knows which are these systems that manages paid wifi networks and some hotels and airports?

Even better, would anyone know a open/free project that would do or could be adapted to that end?

The idea is simple, I want to let the network open at physical level so anyone can connect. After connected however, the clients would have access only to a specified page where they can logging in, and doing the necessary validations the router would allow these of those ports (or even everything) for his IP.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on the wireless router that you use, you can flash the device to [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) and use it as a hotspot.  There is an option already built in to use the [AnchorFree](http://www.anchorfree.com/) software and appears to work similar to what hotels provide: paid service wireless. For a tutorial and how to setup a router that's already flashed to DD-WRT with the AnchorFree service look [here](http://thewichitacomputerguy.com/blog/dd-wrt-repeater-bridge-two-ssid-using-anchorfree-wireless): This utilizes two separate routers, one for home setup and the second for the "hosted" wifi.

> One of the new features of the DD-WRT v24 firmware is a HotSpot Revenue generator called: AnchorFree. This posts an ad generated in a frame at the top of the browser window, through AnchorFree's network of advertisers. **When someone clicks on the ad, the person hosting the router gets a little chunk of change from the click**.

Flashing the router depends on the router make and model.  Check out the DD-WRT website for more info on that.

If AnchorFree isn't exactly what you are looking for, built in the DD-WRT is also SputNik:

> SputnikNet is the super-flexible, web-based management **and captive portal authentication** system for Wi-Fi hotspots and hotzones. Manage one or thousands of hotspots with SputnikNet. SputnikNet enables you to:
>
> - auto-provision Wi-Fi access points (APs) by plugging them into broadband
> - manage Wi-Fi APs centrally, over a secure Web connection
> - **design captive portals with your brand**
> - authenticate users and devices for free or paid Wi-Fi
> - track usage by access point and Wi-Fi end user

It appears that SputNik might be the closest to what you are looking for.  [Here](http://docs.sputnik.com/manuals/agent/lessons/4042) is a how to in using sputnik.  You can also [purchase](http://www.sputnik.com/products/wifi_devices/) a sputnik ready device, instead of flashing the router yourself.

Comment: as an alternative to flashing a router with custom firmware, which usually voids its warranty, by running a linux distro as a router/captive portal between your modem and your wifi access points, such as http://www.zeroshell.org/hotspot-router

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you're talking about the feature is called either **[Captive Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)** or **802.1x / RADIUS** authentication.  They do different things, but both fit your question description.  There are a number of systems that support both or either option.

Comment: It should be pointed out that Captive Portal and 802.1x / RADIUS are completely different technologies (not just two names for the same thing). They could both solve the problem, though.