# when people connect to my wifi how can i set it for them to see a website?

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hotel like Wifi manager](https://superuser.com/questions/183105/hotel-like-wifi-manager)

I have a mac with snow leopard. Is there software that I can download and setup that if a person connects to my wifi they see a website kind of like how coffee shops or hotels do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hotel like Wifi manager](http://superuser.com/questions/183105/hotel-like-wifi-manager) (as I doubt you really want to use your Mac rather than your wireless router to control your Wifi?)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called a "[captive portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)". There are a number of ways to do that. Probably the easiest way is to use the appropriate DD-WRT image on a supported wireless router. You might want to take a look at [this article for how to make something like that on an OS X box](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/188).

Answer (score -1):

You might try looking through the options on your wireless router, there may be an option to set a default web page.