# OpenWRT: Redirect all Wi-Fi users to some page and don't allow access EXCEPT range of permitted MACs?

Tags: openwrt

I have an AP, currently running OpenWRT 14.07 (BarrierBreaker), and i want to disable the internet access for all Wi-Fi clients, redirecting them to some local page (virtual host with IP, actually), except number of predefined, permitted MAC addresses that i know.

So, what should happen:
Someone connects to my AP, then DHCP gives that client an address (default gateway, too), and when he/she trying to reach the Web (requests something on port 80/443 through HTTP/HTTPS), if client's MAC is not on the list of permitted ones, a redirection to the virtual host should happen in order to show him/her some page that i want to show and all access should be denied (except the virtual host, of course).

Additionally, in background, if the client tries to use some other service on other port, for example DNS, a comparing in the list of allowed MACs should happen again, and only if the client MAC exists, the request can be done.

How something like that can be realized?

Comment: You do understand that filtering by Mac Address is beyond pointless right?  In order for a client to be connected their mac address is broadcasted in plain text.  All anyone has to do is know this, clone the address, and just connect to the network provided they know the password.  Your idea is no different.  Its stupid simply to get around.

Comment: I know pretty well, but in this case, the setup will be used by not so technical competented users.

Comment: What you basically describe is a captive portal.  There are versions/modifications you can make to OpenWRT in order to add this capability to it.  You might have to make modifications to the captive portal to allow specific ports or just change your plan slightly if you don't have the skills required to implement something yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hotel like Wifi manager](https://superuser.com/questions/183105/hotel-like-wifi-manager)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "Captive portal". I don't run one now but tried "ChilliSpot" which now is defunct.

OpenWRT wiki suggest [Nodogsplash](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.hotspot.nodogsplash).